# Full Path seems incorrect after update to Assets 2.0.4

Tags: assets

After updating to Assets 2.0.4 on EE 2.5.1, I noticed that that when I view a custom Assets field, the previously defined upload directories are no longer checked.

After some digging around the assets database tables, I noticed some odd inconsistencies: http://jon.ee/image/2l0B2w2v3A3Y (Screenshot)

All of my images display properly on the front-end.

- What could be causing the upload paths to be unchecked on custom Assets filled
- Should the full_path column be filled in, and is this causing the issue?

Comment: From what version did you upgrade from, Jon?
Also, full_path column should be empty for top level folders (parent_id set to NULL).

Comment: I upgraded from 1.2.2. Looks like database is correct then.  I didn't fully understand the changes Assets 2 made, so it made me nervous that the column was empty.

Comment: That said, My Upload directories aren't checked when viewing a custom Assets field.  Any ideas on this one?

Comment: So updating from 1 to 2 lost your Assets field settings? (Namely - allowed upload folders)

Comment: It seems that all of the settings are still there, the boxes just aren't checked.

Comment: That's odd - we'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed since Assets 2.2. [See changelog](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/changelog.html).